# Get Unicode value from range in Excel with VBA

Tags: xml, excel, character-encoding, vba

I have an Excel file and an XML file.  The data in Excel is written in either Russian or Armenian and is Unicode encoded. I would like to get data from Excel and write to XML.
When I get the range's value from Excel in VBA I see this string: `??????`.

Is there any way to change the encoding on a Range value like this?

Comment: I am guessing that English isn't your first language. However I cannot work out what you are trying to ask. Can you post some code and try to ask a specific question so that we can help you?

Comment: See this article, it might help you figure out what happens and if you actually still have a problem: http://blog.brettski.com/2009/12/04/vba-convert-unicode-to-ascii/